# angular cli : selectors unknown during tests

Tags: angular, jasmine, components, selector, angular-cli

I'm learning how to do my first tests with Angular 2, using `angular-cli`.

When I create a new component `MyComponent`, then add its selector `app-mycomponent` into the app template, then all tests fail and say that `app-mycomponent` is unknown.

This problem occurs only in tests; if I start the app then everything is fine.

My environment:

```
npm : 3.10.10
node : 6.9.5
angular-cli : 1.0.0-beta.32.3
jasmine-core: 2.5.2
protractor: 5.1.0
```

Rather than copying tons of config files, here are steps to reproduce:

1. create a new project

   ```
   ng new testproj
   cd testproj
   ```
2. create a component

   ```
   ng generate component mycomp
   ```
3. go to `./src/mycomp/mycomp.component.ts` and note its selector (should be `app-mycomp`)
4. edit `./src/app/component.html` and add this line:

   ```
   <app-mycomp></app-mycomp>
   ```

   where `app-mycomp` is the selector you saw in step 3.
5. launch the tests:

   ```
   ng test
   ```

then here the failures reported :

```
Error: Template parse errors:
'app-mycomp' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-mycomp' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-mycomp' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
{{title}}</h1>
[ERROR ->]<app-mycomp></app-mycomp>"): AppComponent@3:0
```

Is it a bug, or have I done something wrong? I've tried manually setting `MyComponent` as a `provider` into `AppComponent`, same problem.

Comment: Have you added `MyComponent` as a `declaration` when configuring the `TestBed` for `src/app/app.component.spec.ts`? That should be step 5; when you add the component to the template, you also need to make sure it's made available in the tests.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : this is a part i am figuring, but angular cli seems to do this for me, in my spec file it use beforEach twice where it does : beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComponent]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

Comment: That looks like the test for MyComponent, but the error looks like its for the test for AppComponent. That is the test where you need to add the MyComponent to the declarations

Comment: AppComponent uses MyComponent, so you need to add it to the declarations in the test. With TestBed, you are configuring a module from scratch. So what ever is needed for the component to work, you need to add it to the test bed

Comment: Please [edit] the question. The CLI can add the new component to the module (so it works when you serve it) but does **not** add it into the tests for the app component (because it doesn't know that's where you plan to use it - you add it there *after* creation. It's useful, it's not magic.

Comment: thanks to you all, i now understand what was going on, i'm going to edit my question to give the answer.

By the way, thank you jonrsharpe for having corrected my poor english :)

Comment: Do not edit your question to give the answer; if you've solved the problem, write an answer below or delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to comments above I figured out what was going wrong:
AppComponent test module didn't knew how to use MyComponent. I don't know yet what is going on under the hood when the test is loaded, anyway we have to specify manually all component dependancies into its test by this way :
In app.module.spec.ts, edit beforeEach method that is calling TestBed.configureTestingModule.

**before :**

```
beforeEach(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
});
```

**after :**

```
beforeEach(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent , 
    MyComponent
  ],
});
```